# Pandas dataframe: How to create multiple columns of different lagged values with groubpy in one call?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

End goal: have n lagged (named) feature values in every row of a pandas dataframe respecting group

Secondary goal: No for loops in pandas call

A naive implementation could be:

```
n = 7
for feature in features:
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        df[feature + "_" + str(i)] = df.groupby(["a", "b"])[feature].shift(i)
```

I would like to have something like this instead, saving len(features) * n - 1 calls to the pandas api:

```
lagged_features = {}
n = 7
for feature in features:
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        key = feature + "_" + str(i)
        lagged_features[key] = pd.NamedAgg(feature, lambda x: x.shift(i))

df_lagged = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).agg(**lagged_features)
```

However agg doesn't like shift :(

And you get a `ValueError: Must produce aggregated value`

I believe you should be able to use apply? But, I can only think of a way to get the number of calls down to n (much better, but it would be so much cleaner if you could do something like agg)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample input and expected output? (in text form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial approach attempted to use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby().agg()`, but, `.agg()` method requires functions that return a single value per group, and `shift()` does not meet this requirement as it returns a `Series` instead.

To solve this problem, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby().apply()` as you mentioned. This function allows you to apply a function that returns a `DataFrame` to each group.

Here is an example. It's a solution where you only need to call the pandas API once for each group:

```py
import pandas as pd

n = 2
features = ['feature1', 'feature2']

def lag_features(grp):
    lags = {f'{feature}_{i}': grp[feature].shift(i) for feature in features for i in range(1, n + 1)}
    return pd.DataFrame(lags)

df_lagged = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).apply(lag_features).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
```

**Explanation**

- `lag_features(grp)` is a helper function that gets applied to each group. It takes a `DataFrame` (a single group) as input. Inside this function, a dictionary comprehension is used to generate the lagged features for each feature in the group. This dictionary is then transformed into `DataFrame`, which is returned by the function.
- `df.groupby(["a", "b"]).apply(lag_features)` groups the `DataFrame` by `a` and `b`, then applies `lag_features(grp)` to each group. This gives us a `DataFrame` with multi-index where the 3-rd level of the index is the original DataFrame's index.
- `reset_index(level=2, drop=True)` is used to remove this 3rd level of the index

Comment: Thanks. This still has a for loop that calls pandas to walk through the data n times, but I suppose it cannot be avoided. Anyways I'm not even familiar with the inner workings of agg, so it might be walking through the data multiple times anyways (hopefully not, but it's not that important right now for me to check)